# Implement Asynchronous Download (NSURLConnection) on separate NSThread?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

This may sounds weird but please bear with me. I have 6-7 API calls which make request to a server one by one. I want to implement these calls in a separate thread. But when I do this, none of my delegate methods (of NSURLConnection) gets called even after managing a separate NSRunloop 
 ([[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];)

Can anyone suggests me alternative approach for the same or any correction in existing functionality??

Answer (score 0):

Use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) instead. It's much easier to use than `NSURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

a quick google threw up this: http://blog.emmerinc.be/index.php/2009/03/15/multiple-async-nsurlconnections-example/ he is using a dictionary to manage multiple requests

Comment: Hi JFoulkes,  The obstacle which I am stuck in is not related with multiple NSURLConnections. Instead it is regarding managing connections in a seperate NSThread. As I mentioned above, requests are going in sequential order one by one. I have googled it and found stuff like, NSOperation but it doesn't give me exact idea of what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Using a separate thread for each NSURLConnection, which is already multithreaded is a bad idea. It's just pointlessly using system resources and defeating NSURLConnections attempts to manage connections optimally. However, it does work so if you are not receiving delegate messages you are doing something wrong. Rather than find an alternative way todo it you should try to get to the bottom of your problem with the runloop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest to do the similar operation. Go through the following code change the downloadAllIcons method to suit your requirement,

```
  [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(downloadAllIcons:) toTarget:self withObject:xmlData];

 -(void) downloadAllIcons:(NSData *)_xmlData
 {

 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSArray *IconList= PerformXMLXPathQuery(_xmlData,@"//icon");
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:IconList forKey:@"IconList"];


 for (int i=0; i<[IconList count]; i++) {

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[[IconList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nodeContent"]]==nil) {
        NSData * responseData=[self downloadProccessedImage:[[IconList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nodeContent"]];


        if(responseData)
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:responseData forKey:[[IconList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nodeContent"]];
        //NSLog(@"%@",[[IconList objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"nodeContent"]);
    }



}
[pool release];



 }


 -(id) downloadProccessedImage:(NSString *)_URL
  {


NSData *response=nil;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_URL];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:60];
[ASIHTTPRequest setShouldThrottleBandwidthForWWAN:YES];
[request startSynchronous];
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error)
{
    response = [request responseData];
}       
return response;

    }
```